# Transfer files from AWS S3 to Unix Server using SFTP

Tags: python, amazon-s3, sftp, boto3, paramiko

I am trying to use the paramiko and boto3 libraries in Python to transfer files from a S3 bucket to an Unix server. Currently I am able to achieve this by bringing the file to local by using the download method. Then i will use the ftp client to upload the file to Unix server. Is there a simple way to do this directly from s3 to unix server without bringing the file to local?

Comment: Depends on what you mean *"directly"*. If you want to save a bandwidth, then probably not. If you want to just avoid storing the file locally, then it should be possible.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl What i meant by directly, is to avoid bringing the file to local, or avoid reading the file data and transferring (the files are huge, ~4GB gzip). I would like to know how to do this by avoiding locally storing the file. Thank you

Comment: *"avoid bringing the file to local"* - That does not answer my question. It is as ambiguous as your question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Apologies, if I am being unclear here. I am running the python code from a windows machine. I don't want to download the file to the windows directory and then upload it to Unix server. Because downloading the file from S3 takes time (due to size issues).

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly a simple API what will allow you to transfer a file between two remote S3 and FTP servers.

But of course, you can either:

- initiate the download from S3 on the Unix server, or
- setup a server on AWS that will push/upload the file to the Unix server.